# Angular dynamic filter placeholder/fallback text?

Tags: angular, filter, filtering, fallback

I'm attempting to create a placeholder text fallback for a dynamic filter, but can not get this working and am not sure if it is actually possible?

The filter code is:

```
*ngFor="let example of scale.examples | filter:{type: 'solo'}
```

I would like to be able to specify placeholder/fallback text if the filter type is not matched.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by fallback? Are you saying if the filter returns 0 results, then you want to show some placeholder text?

Comment: Is it AngularJS or Angular? Your title says AngularJS but code is for Angular!!

Comment: Yes some placeholder text if the filter returns zero results. This is Angular 4, I am using it within an Ionic 3 app. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply pipes almost anywhere. So you can do something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="(scale.examples | filter:{ 'type': 'solo' }).length === 0">No Values</div>
<div *ngFor="let example of scale.examples | filter:{ 'type': 'solo' }">
   {{example.value}} 
</div>
```

Here's a working Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/LxRRTdFL4dI9QwjmX3WY?p=preview

### Update

If you don't want the overhead of sorting the array twice you can use the new **ngIf else** syntax:

```
<div *ngIf="(myArr | filter:{ 'type': 'triple' }); let filteredArr" style="color: blue;">
  <div *ngIf="filteredArr.length === 0">No Results</div>
  <div *ngFor="let myObj of filteredArr" style="color: blue;">
    {{myObj.value}} 
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a working Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/MaipzWGZ06ViG1WNzDVW?p=preview

If you want it to be more elegant, than it's best you sort the array on the component side and just use that.

Comment: Thanks, that works (and I have implemented it), however I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: I've added another way to do this as well

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.